# How to calculate a path entropy in the context of information theory?

Tags: probability, distributions, markov-process, entropy, information-theory

Consider a path where the system goes from states $i$ to $j$ and then from $j$ to $k$. Given that the probability of finding the system in state $i$ is $p_i$ and the transition probabilities are $p_{ij}$ and $p_{jk}$, what is the path entropy of the path $i \rightarrow j \rightarrow k$?

To my understanding, the probability of having such a path is $p_{i}p_{ij}p_{jk}$, so the Shannon entropy is $H=-\sum_{ij}p_{i}p_{ij}p_{jk}\log p_{i}p_{ij}p_{jk}$. This understanding is consistent with Equation (6) in [this paper](https://isl.stanford.edu/%7Ecover/papers/paper101.pdf). However, from another [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ct5001389), it seems that the path entropy should be $H=-\sum_{ij}p_{i}p_{ij}p_{jk}\log p_{ij}p_{jk}$ instead. (See Equation 4 in the figure below, which does not account for $p_i$ in the log term.) Which one is correct?

[image]